# Understanding character pointers in a while loop

Tags: c, string, pointers, while-loop

I am learning C and a I came across this function in my study materials. The function accepts a string pointer and a character and counts the number of characters that are in the string.  For example for a string `this is a string` and a `ch = 'i'` the function would return `3` for 3 occurrences of the letter `i`.

The part I found confusing is in the while loop.  I would have expected that to read something like `while(buffer[j] != '\0')` where the program would cycle through each element `j` until it reads a null value.  I don't get how the while loop works using `buffer` in the while loop, and how the program is incremented character by character using `buffer++` until the null value is reached.  I tried to use debug, but it doesn't work for some reason.  Thanks in advance.

```
int charcount(char *buffer, char ch)
{
int ccount = 0;
while(*buffer != '\0')
{
    if(*buffer == ch)
        ccount++;
    buffer++;
}
return ccount;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer` is a pointer to a set of chars, a string, or a memory buffer holding char data.

`*buffer` will dereference the value at `buffer`, as a char. This can be compared with the null character.

When you add to `buffer` - you are adding to the address, not the value it points to, `buffer++` adds 1 to the address, pointing to the next char. This means that now `*buffer` results in the next character.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are incrementing the pointer `buffer` until it points to the null character, at which point you know you scanned the whole string. Instead of `buffer[j]`, which is equivalent to `*(buffer+j)`, we are incrementing the pointer itself.

When you say `buffer++` you increment the address stored in `buffer` by one.

Once you internalize how pointers work, this code is cleaner than the code that uses a separate index to scan the character string.

Comment: **buffer++** in line 8

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, arrays are stored in sequence, and an array is stored according to its first address and length.

Therefore *buffer is actually the address of the first byte, and is synonymous with buffer[0]. Because of this, you can use `buffer` as an array, like this:

```
int charcount(char *buffer, char ch)
{
    int ccount = 0;
    int charno = 0;
    while(buffer[charno] != '\0')
    {
        if(buffer[charno] == ch)
            ccount++;
        charno++;
    }
    return ccount;  
}
```

Note that this works *because strings are null terminated* - if you don't have a null termination in the character array pointed to by `*buffer` it will continue reading forever; you lose the bit where c knows how long the array is. This is why you see so many c functions to which you pass a pointer and a length - the pointer tells it the `[0]` position of the array, and the size you specify tells it how far to keep reading.

Hope this helps.